# How to consolidate selected files from multiple sub-directories into one directory

Tags: shell, unix, file-io

I know this is probably elementary to unix people, but I haven't found a straightforward answer online.

I have a directory with sub-directories. Some of these sub-dirs have .mov files in them. I want to consolidate all the movs to a single directory. I don't need to worry about file naming conflicts because the files are from a digital camera and it names the files incrementally, but divides them into daily folders.

What is the Unix-fu for grabbing all these files and copying (or even better, moving them) to a directory in my home folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mv `find . -name "*.mov" | xargs` OUTPUTDIR/
```

**Update** after thkala's comment:

```
find . -iname "*.mov" | while read line; do mv "$line" OUTPUTDIR/; done
```

Comment: Doesn't this break if the files have whitespace in their names? Or if there's just too many of them? Although it does solve the directory overlap issue of my answer...

Comment: Thanks! Your final suggestion  (find . -iname "*.mov" | while read line; do cp "$line" OUTPUT_DIR/; done) worked perfectly. It's also the most comprehensible to me, the non-expert unix user. I tried to understand the xargs solutions, and read up on xargs, but still don't understand how that command works.

Comment: @beibel `xargs` reads its standard input and makes a command-line argument list. If called without arguments, it prints arguments on one line.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
find "$SOURCE_DIRECTORY" -type f -name '*.mov' -exec mv '{}' "$TARGET_DIRECTORY" ';'
```

If the source and target directories do not overlap this should work fine.

EDIT:

BTW, if you have mixed-case extensions (x.mov, y.Mov, Z.MOV) as is the case with many cameras, this would be better. It uses -iname which is case-insensitive when matching:

```
find "$SOURCE_DIRECTORY" -type f -iname '*.mov' -exec mv '{}' "$TARGET_DIRECTORY" ';'
```

Make sure to replace the $SOURCE_DIRECTORY and $TARGET_DIRECTORY variables with the actual directories and that they do not overlap (i.e. the target being somewhere under the source)

EDIT 2:

PS: I just noticed that khachik caught this one with his edit

Comment: @thkala I don't know why, but the code doesn't work, or deletes or "*.mov" files...

Comment: @khachik You did replace $SOURCE_DIRECTORY and $TARGETDIRECTORY with your actual paths, right? Because it works just fine here...

Comment: @khachik: Would you mind telling me your OS, shell, mv and find version, as well as the exact way it fails ? I'd like to get to the bottom of this...

Comment: @thkala `GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin9.0)` on mac 10.5.8. Command: `find . -type f -name '*.mov' -exec mv '{}' "OU/" ';'`, Error: `mv: rename ./a/1 2.mov to OU/: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Uh... I thought at first it's the whitespace, but this works fine here with GNU findutils (which find does macOS have?). Are you sure that OU/ should not be OUT/ as in your previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cope with weird filenames (spaces, special characters), try this:

```
$ cd <source parent directory>
$ find -name '*.mov' -print0 | xargs -0 echo mv -v -t <target directory>
```

Remove the "echo" above to actually do the move, rather than print what would happen.

"mv -v" gives verbose output, "mv -t ..." specifies the target directory (possibly GNU-specific).

"-print0" and "-0" are extensions to cope with weird filenames. On non-GNU systems you might need to remove those options, which will result in newline-separated data. This will still work on filenames with spaces, but not filenames with newlines (yes, it's possible).

Comment: I think xargs without the -0 will separate arguments at each whitespace rather than just newline. At least mine is like that...